# How to write order by in linq

Tags: linq

This code output is like this

```
a  1          
b  12
```

I wont to get out put like this

```
b  12             
a  1
```

Query:

```
var x1 = (from v in db3.VoteRecords
          join v2 in db3.Partis on v.PartiID equals v2.ID
          where v.ProvinceID == (int)cmbProvience.SelectedValue 
          && v.DistrictID == (int)cmbDistrict.SelectedValue
          group v by new { v2.PartiName } into g
          select new
          {
              Parti = g.Key.PartiName,
              Votes = (from vt in g
                       select g.Key.PartiName).Count()         
          });
          dataGridView1.DataSource = x1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this at the end

```
{
    Parti = g.Key.PartiName,
    Votes = (from vt in g
             select g.Key.PartiName).Count()

}).OrderByDescending(l =>l.Parti);
```

If you want to order by the `Votes` column. Do this:

```
{
    Parti = g.Key.PartiName,
    Votes = (from vt in g
             select g.Key.PartiName).Count()

}).OrderByDescending(l =>l.Votes);
```

Or if you first want to order by `Parti` and then by `Votes` do this:

```
{
    Parti = g.Key.PartiName,
    Votes = (from vt in g
             select g.Key.PartiName).Count()

}).OrderByDescending(l =>l.Parti).ThenByDescending (l =>l.Votes);
```

Or if you first want to order by `Votes` and then by `Parti` do this:

```
{
    Parti = g.Key.PartiName,
    Votes = (from vt in g
             select g.Key.PartiName).Count()

}).OrderByDescending(l =>l.Votes ).ThenByDescending (l =>l.Parti);
```